# An $\aleph_2$-cc forcing which is not proper but doesn't collapse $\omega_1$

Tags: set-theory, examples-counterexamples, forcing

My question(s) is the following:

- Is there a non-proper forcing notion which has the $\aleph_2$-cc property and doesn't collapse $\omega_1$?
- Is it consistent that such a forcing notion exists?

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Assuming CH club shooting is an example.

Comment: @AsafKaragila right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly consistent, yes.

Assume $\sf CH$, and let $S\subseteq\omega_1$ be a stationary co-stationary set. Then the standard club shooting forcing, using closed subsets of $S$ ordered by end-extension, is not proper, since it kills the properness of $\omega_1\setminus S$, but by cardinality arguments alone it has size $\aleph_1$ so it has $\aleph_2$-c.c.

Note that this forcing is generally $S$-proper, so it might not be exactly what you're after.

Presumably you can modify this so that the club added is more like a Baumgartner club using finite conditions, which should be provably $\aleph_2$-c.c. in just $\sf ZFC$.